# Is the limit of non-decreasing sequence that is bounded equal to the upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I'm playing with one of theorem in my notes:

**Theorem**

> If a convergent sequence $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} = L$ that is
>   bounded by $M$, then $|L| \leq M$

I wonder is there a connection between $L$ and $M$ if the sequence is non-decreasing? In other words, is it always true that $L = M$ for non-decreasing sequence that is bounded?
I can't find a counterexampe, as well as a convincing arugment to connect $L$ and $M$. A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $M$ can be of course larger than $L$. Think about $a_n=1-1/n$ and $M=2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *least* upper bound is equal to the limit. To show this, let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the definition of the least upper bound, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $M - \varepsilon < a_N$. Since the sequence is non-decreasing, we have:

$$
\forall n > N : M - \varepsilon < a_N \le a_n
$$

Given that $a_n \le M$, Rearrange to get the definition of the limit:

$$
\forall n > N : |a_n - M| < \varepsilon
$$